# PowerBI - Count number of occurrences of each unique value per day

Tags: powerbi

Snippet of data i am working with:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpSep.png)

this table shows the number of times that a specific computer (machine) connected to the system for a specific date & time.

What i need help with is to count the number of times a specific computer connected per day.

i used the following calculation to count the total number of connections per a machine over the complete range of data: (Terminal being the name of the table)

Summary = SUMMARIZE(Terminal, Terminal[machine], "Connections", COUNT(Terminal[number]))

this is the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjEOA.png)

But in order for me to add the desired visuals to my report i need to add in the dates.

what i would like to see is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9xln.png)

I really hope someone can guide me in the right direction.

I tried to group the stations by date, but i could not figure it out either.

I have only recently started working with powerbi so i am very new to this all.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Summary = SUMMARIZE(Terminal, Terminal[machine], Terminal[Date], "Connections", COUNT(Terminal[number]))
```